# What is Class E3 airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, class-e-airspace

I am not aware of Class e3 airspace that is now associated in an area I used to be able to fly my ultralight, model airplane, or drone.  It is now apparently requiring FAA authorization.

Comment: If this user were still active, I would ask if his problem has been result.  To the best of my knowledge, E3 airspace is currently not in the gridded (authorization-required) portion of the LAANC map for authorization for flying unmanned aircraft (model airplanes, drones).  Also, I would very much like to know if an FAA staffer has directly told him that he needs authorization to fly his paramotor in E3 airspace.  Ping me if you ever come back, FECK, please.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like its an [extension of Class C Airspace](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2005/10/13/05-20466/establishment-of-class-e3-airspace-riverside-march-field-ca) from a class E3 [announcement](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2005/10/13/05-20466/establishment-of-class-e3-airspace-riverside-march-field-ca),

> ...Class E3 airspace areas are designated as arrival extensions to a
>   Class C surface area. Class E arrival extensions are primarily
>   designated to provide additional controlled airspace ancillary to a
>   surface area to protect instrument operations for the primary airport,
>   without imposing additional communications burdens on airspace users.

Comment: Do you know how to find out when this became active at a certain airport or airbase?

Comment: You may want to get on the [FAA eMail list](https://www.faa.gov/contact/subscribe/). I get most of my alerts form the [AOPA member service alert list which send out local info like this.](https://www.aopa.org/). My local FBO also generally posts this kinda stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of E3 airspace is spelled out in several answers to this related question-- [What are E2 and E4 airspace?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64227/what-are-e2-and-e4-airspace)

Comment: It would be good to include at least a brief explanation here.